# Left joining tables and counting distinct values with SQL

Tags: mysql, join

I am new to MySQL. I have a script that writes 7 files to a MySQL database. I access it using myphpadmin ( feel free to suggest better GUI ).

Each of the 7 tables has one column that interests me - `gclid`.

My goal is to calculate how many unique values are in each table column named 'gclid' and be able to sort it by date since each table `have a date / timestamp` next to the `gclid`.

Table names are:

```
full_google
full_cf_click
full_cf_session_init
full_clickout_database
full_clickout_HO
full_conversions_HO
full_conversions_api
```

Example of 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE full_google (
    Date text,
    Hour text,
    Gclid text,
);

INSERT INTO full_google (Date, Hour, Gclid)
VALUES (2019-12-02, 00, CjwKCAiA5o3vBRBUEiwA9PVz),
(2019-12-02, 00, CjwKCAiA5fo3vBRBUEiwA9PVz),
(2019-12-02, 00, CjwKCAiA5o3vBRBUEiwAf9PVz);
```

```
CREATE TABLE full_session_start (
    Date text,
    Hour text,
    Gclid text,
);

INSERT INTO full_session_start (Date, Hour, Gclid)
VALUES (2019-12-02, 00, CjwKCAifA5o3vBRBUEiwA9PVz),
(2019-12-02, 00, CjwKCAiA5fod3vBRBUEiwA9PVz),
(2019-12-02, 00, CjwKCAiA5os3vBRBUEiwAf9PVz);
```

full_clickout_api

```
CREATE TABLE full_clickout_api (
    Date text,
    Hour text,
    Gclid text,
);

INSERT INTO full_clickout_api (Date, Hour, Gclid)
VALUES (2019-12-02, 00, CjwKCdAiA5o3vBRBUEiwA9PVz),
(2019-12-02, 00, CjwKCAifA5fo3vBRBUEiwA9PVz),
(2019-12-02, 00, CjwKCAiA5o3dvBRBUEiwAf9PVz);
```

full_google

```
Date             Hour  Gclid
2019-12-02       0     CjwKCAiA5ow3vBRBUEiwA9PVz
2019-12-02       0     CjwKCAiA5o3vBRgBUEiwA9PVz
2019-12-02       0     CjwKCAiA5wo3vBRBUEiwA9PVz
2019-12-02       0     CjwKCAiA5o3vBRBUEiwA9PVz
```

full_session_start

```
Date             Hour  Gclid
2019-12-02       0     CjwKCAiA5o3veBRBUEiwA9PVz
2019-12-02       0     CjwKCAiA5o3vBgRBUEiwA9PVz
2019-12-02       0     CjwKCAiA5o3rvBRBUEiwA9PVz
2019-12-02       0     CjwKCAiA5o3evBRBUEiwA9PVz
```

full_clickout_api

```
Date             Hour  Gclid
2019-12-02       0     CjwKCAiA5o3veBRBUEiwA9PVz
2019-12-02       0     CjwKCAiA5o3vBgRBUEiwA9PVz
2019-12-02       0     CjwKCAiA5o3rvBRBUEiwA9PVz
2019-12-02       0     CjwKCAiA5o3evBRBUEiwA9PVz
```

What I have tried so far:

```
CREATE temporary TABLE counts AS SELECT full_google.date, 
       , 
       Count(DISTINCT(full_google.gclid))                       AS total_distinct_gclid_in_google ,
       Count(DISTINCT(full_cf_click.click_id_from_request_url)) AS total_distinct_gclid_in_cf , 
       Count(DISTINCT(full_cf_session_init.gclid))              AS total_distinct_gclid_in_session_start ,
       Count(DISTINCT(full_session_start.gclid))                AS total_distinct_gclid_in_cf , 
       Count(DISTINCT(full_clickout_database.gclid))            AS total_distinct_gclid_in_clickout_database ,
       Count(DISTINCT(full_clickout_ho.gclid))                  AS total_distinct_gclid_in_HO , 
       Count(DISTINCT(full_conversions_ho.gclid))               AS total_distinct_gclid_in_conversion_HO ,
       Count(DISTINCT(full_conversions_api.gclid))              AS total_distinct_gclid_in_database
```

So far I have selected and counted the items that interest me, moving on forward I am not sure how I should join these tables and have the following view:

```
Date         total_distinct_gclid_in_google   total_distinct_gclid_in_cf   total_distinct_gclid_in_session_start   total_distinct_gclid_in_cf   total_distinct_gclid_in_clickout_database   total_distinct_gclid_in_HO   total_distinct_gclid_in_conversion_HO   total_distinct_gclid_in_database
2019-12-07   500                              450                          400                                     350                          300                                         250                          200                                     150   
2019-12-08   600                              452                          417                                     755                          321                                         755                          457                                     727
2019-12-09   500                              450                          400                                     350                          300                                         250                          200                                     150
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let's pretend there are 3 tables. Now see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Hi, I have provided sufficient information - the structure of my data, names of the tables and my desired output as well as what I have tried so far, not sure what you still find insufficient to reproduce the data at your end.

Comment: Yep, that works too.

Comment: Actually you didn't.   You did not provide the structure of the data -- I see no data types anywhere in your question.  In addition, the SQL is clearly invalid (eg there is no from clause)  --

Comment: Hoogan, I understand it is not complete, that is the reason I am asking stack overflow a question because I do not know how to proceed with my query to join the table values and get the desired output.

Comment: Strawberry, I have added create and insert statements, does that help or this question would need additional information?

Comment: No. What works is providing an MCRE as requested.

Comment: I have added examples to create 3 tables that have the same structure amongst the 7 files. If that is not enough, could you let me know what else I should provide?

Comment: See my answer... but one warning -- I doubt you want to store dates as text.

Comment: Hogan, thank you, will try the code once I adjust it to my data. I believe the issues would come up if Date is stored as text and the format of dates differ through the tables?

Comment: Yes if date is different in the different tables then you need to normalize for this to work -- no matter what you do -- you can normalize in the query or adjust the tables first.

Answer (score 0):

Given the little you have shown us I have to guess at what is actually going on -- based on that I would probably do it like this:

```
SELECT
  DATE, 
  full_google_g.c,
  full_cf_click_g.c,
  full_cf_session_init_g.c,
  full_clickout_database_g.c,
  full_clickout_HO_g.c,
  full_conversions_HO_g.c,
  full_conversions_api_g.c
FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM full_google
       UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM full_cf_click
       UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM full_cf_session_init
       UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM full_clickout_database
       UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM full_clickout_HO
       UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM full_conversions_HO
       UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM full_conversions_api
) as DATELIST
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT Gclid) AS C FROM full_google GROUP BY DATE
) as full_google_g on full_google_g.DATE = DATELIST.DATE
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT Gclid) AS C  FROM full_cf_click GROUP BY DATE
) as full_cf_click_g on full_cf_click_g.DATE = DATELIST.DATE
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT Gclid) AS C  FROM full_cf_session_init GROUP BY DATE
) as full_cf_session_init_g on full_cf_session_init_g.DATE = DATELIST.DATE
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT Gclid) AS C  FROM full_clickout_database GROUP BY DATE
) as full_clickout_database_g on full_clickout_database_g.DATE = DATELIST.DATE
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT Gclid) AS C  FROM full_clickout_HO GROUP BY DATE
) as full_clickout_HO_g on full_clickout_HO_g.DATE = DATELIST.DATE
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT Gclid) AS C  FROM full_conversions_HO GROUP BY DATE
) as full_conversions_HO_g on full_conversions_HO_g.DATE = DATELIST.DATE
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT Gclid) AS C  FROM full_conversions_api GROUP BY DATE
) as full_conversions_api_g on full_conversions_api_g.DATE = DATELIST.DATE
```

What I'm doing:  I'm getting a list of rows (dates) by first looking at all the joined tables and extracting a distinct list of dates from them.  Then I'm left joining all the counts from each of those tables, in the select I put each count in a different column.

> If you have a dates table you can change sub-query DATELIST to select from that.